# UITableViewCell re-ordering: cell stops moving 10 pixels into the drag

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I've got a `UITableView` which I've wired up to be editable.

Tapping and holding causes the "displace" animation to appear (the row being drawn "above" the rest of the table). So far, so good.

But, moving the row any more than about 10 pixels causes the cell to return to its original position, and I can never move any row to any other position.

A breakpoint reveals that `-tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:` is definitely being called, albeit with the same index path as the source and destination rows.

Can any psychic debuggers shed some light on this?

**EDIT**
Some more relevant info:

There's a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` on the `UITableViewCell`, but I've made it skip its usual behaviour while the table view it's contained in is in editing mode.

I suspect this might be something to do with it, as `UITableView` reordering is also triggered by a long press.

Comment: Did you managed to solve this problem yet ? I got the very same problem with you. Here is my screen capture of the problem. Here is youtube video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ugxuLNL7BnU

Comment: Did you guys manage to fix this? I have the exact same problem but don't have a ``UILongPressGestureRecognizer``. The strange thing is, is that if I present the view controller modally instead of with pushViewController the drag works.

Answer (score 2):

Probably I've came too late with a solution for you, but it might be helpful to others who encounter the same behavior. The problem you're having is caused by the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` interfering with the long press on the cell's reorder control. You can avoid this behavior by adding `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` on the `cell.contentView` instead of adding it to the cell, since the reorder control it's not in the cell's contentView.

Answer (score 0):

When you move the tableview's cell, do you also move their data source?

for example,

```
NSString* stringToBeMoved = [myArray objectAtIndex:[sourceIndexPath row]];
[stringToBeMoved retain];
[myArray removeObjectAtIndex:[sourceIndexPath row]];
[myArray insertObject:stringToBeMoved atIndex:[destinationIndexPath row]];
[stringToBeMoved release];
```